# Nuxt3: document is not defined

Tags: vuejs3, bootstrap-5, nuxtjs3

I am facing an issue when working with DOM in Nuxt3 SSR mode.
My goal is to toggle a bootstrap modal after loading the page:

```js
<template>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch demo modal
    </button>
    <div class="modal fade" ref="exampleModal" id="exampleModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap'

const exampleModal: Ref<Element | null> = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
    console.log(exampleModal.value)
    const myModal = new Modal(exampleModal.value ?? '')
    myModal.toggle()
})
</script>
```

But it always returns this error:

```
document is not defined

at ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js:908:3
at ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js:7:83
at Object. (./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js:10:3)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:165:29)
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
```

I've turned off SSR mode and it worked well but I need SSR on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with this, my best guess is you probably need to use `if(process.client)` to some capacity in your code to make sure the offending snippets only run in the client not the server.

There's also a template helper for it: 
https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/client-only#clientonly

There is also a `.client.vue` and `.server.vue` file naming convention too you might need to consider in your practices:

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/components#client-components

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwkJY7RaonY

Hope this points you in the right direction until someone can give you a definitive answer...